# Select column from table and add ',' except last row

Tags: sql, firebird

In this

```
SELECT  field + ',' FROM table
```

I get something like this

```
1,
2,
3,
```

But I need to get

```
1,
2,
3
```

Last one should have no comma.

Answer (score 2):

You should check this function

[LIST()](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-aggfuncs-general.html#fblangref40-aggfuncs-list)

Also this question may be duplicated you can check out the question below and see if some answer fit to your needs: [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 1):

It appears Firebird allows you to limit rows with the [`rows`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-dml.html#fblangref40-dml-select-rows) keyword.

Assuming it can also be used in an inline view, you could run the following:

```
select case when x.field is not null
             then t.field
              else t.field  + ','
               end as field_alias
from tbl t
left join
        (
        select field
        from tbl
        order by field desc
        rows 1 to 1
        ) x
           on t.field = x.field
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, this would return you a comma separated list (in one row) of all values in your_column in your_table:

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(your_column) FROM your_table
```

It defaults to using a comma but you can [specify more options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like `SEPARATOR`, `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Firebird has the equivalent [`LIST`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-aggrfunc-list.html)

Comment: Opps, missed his tag :p

Answer (score 0):

If there is a unique field , you can try this way to get the last row without comma.

```
SELECT 
CASE when isnull(B.field,'')='' THEN A.field+',' ELSE A.field END 
FROM [table] A
left join
(
    SELECT TOP 1 field FROM [table] ORDER BY unique_field DESC
)B ON A.field=B.field
ORDER BY A.unique_field
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above MySQL would return comma separated values by default, in the past I've changed the separator to a space -

`GROUP_CONCAT(table_column SEPARATOR " ")`